# Find specific rows with specific conditions

Tags: matlab

E.g. I have the following matrix `Data` with 3 columns: `time` `sat` and `usr`

```
1234 1  1
3134 0  10
34123 0 9
2342 1  10
232 1  1
...
```

Given `selectedusr=[1 10]`, how to select rows in which `usr` is contained in `selectedusr`?

To get `SelectedData`:

```
1234 1  1
3134 0  10
2342 1  10
232 1  1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to select the desired rows:

```
SelectedData = Data(ismember(Data(:,3),selectedusr),:);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SelectedData = Data(any(bsxfun(@eq, Data(:, 3), selectedusr(:)'), 2), :);
```

`bsxfun(@eq, ...)` compares every element of the `usr` column with every element of `selectedusr` and results in a logical array with one column for each element of `selectedusr`. `any(..., 2)` determines rows of this matrix where at least one the logical values is true, resulting in a logical column vector. This is used to select the corresponding rows from `Data` via logical indexing.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. Note `any(bsxfun(@eq ...` is equivalent to `ismember`